# Regular expression to search for whole phrases and single words at the same time in str_detect()

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm confused about regular expressions in `str_detect()`. Here is the setup:

```
library(stringr)

vector_to_check <- c("overall survival (os) in melanoma participants (parts b plus d)", "median overall survival (os)", "one- and two-year overall survival rate will be determined.", "overall survival rate (os rate) at month 6 in all participants")

str_detect(vector_to_check, "rate") 
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

str_detect(vector_to_check , "overall survival (os) in melanoma participants (parts b plus d)")
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Basically, I want to input two types of `pattern` in `str_detect(string, pattern)`:

1. Single words like "rate", "median", etc
2. Whole phrases, like "overall survival (os) in melanoma participants (parts b plus d)"

Is there a regular expression (pattern) that allows for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap with `fixed` as there are metacharacters (`()`) in it, which may need to be either escaped (`\\`) otherwise

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(vector_to_check , fixed("overall survival (os) in melanoma participants (parts b plus d)"))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
str_detect(vector_to_check, fixed("rate")) 
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If we need to combine both,

```
library(purrr)
map(c("rate", "overall survival (os) in melanoma participants (parts b plus d)"), 
  ~ str_detect(vector_to_check, fixed(.x))) %>%
    reduce(`|`)
```

-output

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Can I ask you what `reduce(\`|\`)` does here?

Comment: @HowardBaek `map` returns a list of logical vectors.  which gets reduced to a single logical vector with `|` i.e. OR will return TRUE if any of the list elements are TRUE for each element

Comment: @HowardBaek with `fixed` it should be faster compared to the default regex mode.  I used this instead of collapsing to a single pattern as there is a limit for the length if we collapse

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. `fixed` is a very useful, simple solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the collapse argument of `paste0()` to add an 'or' to any amount of patterns, like this:

```
library(stringr)

vector_to_check <- c("overall survival (os) in melanoma participants (parts b plus d)", "median overall survival (os)", "one- and two-year overall survival rate will be determined.", "overall survival rate (os rate) at month 6 in all participants")

patterns <- c("rate", 
              "overall survival \\(os\\) in melanoma participants \\(parts b plus d\\)")

str_detect(vector_to_check, paste0(patterns, collapse = "|"))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I also added the `\\` in front of the parenthesis, as in regular expression you'll need to escape them!